# Ruby object printing format

Tags: ruby

Consider the following:

```
irb(main):001:0> class A
irb(main):002:1> def initialize
irb(main):003:2> @string = "my string"
irb(main):004:2> end
irb(main):005:1> def to_s
irb(main):006:2> puts @string
irb(main):007:2> end
irb(main):008:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> a = A.new
=> #<A:0x2ea606c @string="my string">
irb(main):010:0> puts a
my string
#<A:0x2ea606c>
=> nil
```

When 'puts' outputs the string my does it also append the refference of the object ?

Is there anyway to get rid of this behavior? What I want outputed is justs the string @string as defined in the classes 'to_s' method

Thanks,

RM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your to_s method to just return @string, not do `puts @string`.